Scroll animation in SwiftUI
I'm trying to find a way to make a similar animation in SwiftUI. The hand image moves to suggest that the view is scrollable, but also the ScrollView is scrolling according to hand image move.
I found an option to use SrollViewReader but it allows only to scroll to the given item (using item id). Is there a way to scroll only some pixels right and left?


Since it's not moving by much, so you could maybe do it by adjusting x-offset. If the main content is given a width that is wider than the screen, the x-offset could adjust which part of the content is actually visible.

Sounds like good idea, I'll check it tomorrow. Thanks a lot for the tip!

@BenzyNeez x-offset adjustment works. Additionally it looks like it should. Thanks again!
